# Atom python IDE, use command line execution?

Tags: python, cmd, atom-editor

I would like to use the Atom IDE since it has nice syntax highlighting for python.

However, when I open a `.py` file in atom, somehow I cannot execute that file in a terminal any more. When I call the `.py` file in the terminal, instead of the output the terminal returns nothing and the atom window starts blinking as if it is forcefully taking priority.

Is there a way to set atom to only work as an editor and leave the execution of files to the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [run-in-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/run-in-terminal) package.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install additional packages to run python scripts using atom. You can check this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuiquBXdA1o) video.

Credit: @Host Promo